# How to store password for Logical Volume in keychain?

Tags: encryption, keychain

I have a *Logical Volume* with UUID 73D724AB-9999-9999-9999-8F1E1F5DF83F and it is password protected. The volume name is Workspace.

The password is very long. Thus, I would like to create an password entry in Keychain Access to mount the password-protected volume automatically.

Question: What should I put in:

- *Keychain Item Name*
- *Kind*
- *Account*  (UUID? or the mount directory)
- *Where*  (UUID? or the mount directory)

Comment: I’ve never tried this with a physical disk, but when I unlock an encrypted disk image, there’s a “Save password in keychain” option. Do you get a similar option when you unlock this volume? If so, that would probably create an appropriate keychain item for you.

Comment: I have this option. My password consists of 60 random chars (special + alpha numeric). So, I would prefer to avoid typing it.

Comment: So I think you just unlock the volume once, by typing in the password, then check “Save password in keychain”, and it should be saved and used when you try to unlock the volume in future.

Comment: I see that I can not avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the correct settings:

```
Kind: Encrypted Volume Password
Account: <UUID>
Where:  <DISK NAME> (as in *Disk Utility*)
```